# How to get Hyperlink of shape at With OpenXML 3.0.1

Tags: c#, hyperlink, openxml

I have word and excel files that have normal hyperlink and hyperlink of shape.
But i can't get Hyperlink object of shape.

Code for Word file:

```
var hyperlinks = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Hyperlink>().ToList();
var hyperlinkRelationships = doc.MainDocumentPart.HyperlinkRelationships.ToList();
```

hyperlinkRelationships return both hyperlink relationship of normal text and shape.
But hyperlinks return only hyperlink of normal text.

Code for Excel file:

```
var hyperlinks = worksheetPart.DrawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing.Descendants<Hyperlink>().ToList();
var hyperlinkRelationships = worksheetPart.DrawingsPart.HyperlinkRelationships.ToList();
```

hyperlinkRelationships return hyperlink relationship of shape. But hyperlinks is an empty list.

Please help me to solve this problem?